# Do static and global modifiers for variables implement a non-modifiable reference?

Tags: php, global-variables, static-variables

[Source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.reference)

The PHP doc says

> PHP implements the static and global modifier for variables in terms
> of references.

```
<?php
function test_global_ref() {
    global $obj;
    $new = new stdClass;
    $obj = &$new;
}

function test_global_noref() {
    global $obj;
    $new = new stdClass;
    $obj = $new;
}

test_global_ref();
var_dump($obj);
test_global_noref();
var_dump($obj);
?>
```

Since the program yields NULL as the first output, is this to say that the implemented reference is non-modifiable(hence the reference to &$new is nullified somehow)? The doc says the implementation results in an unexpected behaviour. Is there a logical explanation to this?

Comment: _a true global variable imported inside a function scope with the global statement actually creates a reference to the global variable_ Looking at this, I simply feel the first one said NULL because it was pointing to the address of a local variable which got garbage collected when the function call finished. See https://onecompiler.com/php/3yxabtfmm

Comment: @nice_dev Interesting thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about global or static, this is about the concept of reference.

Think about the following codes:

```
$a = "a"; $b = "b";

$r = &$a;
var_dump($a, $b, $r); # a, b, a

$r = &$b;
var_dump($a, $b, $r); # a, b, b
```

It's easy to understand, but the important thing is the statement `$r = &$b;` means copy the **reference** of `$b` to `$r`, so *both `$b` and `$r` refer to the same value*.

Next if you do:

```
$r = $a;
var_dump($a, $b, $r); # a, a, a
```

The statement `$r = $a;` means copy the **value** of `$a` to `$r`, so the value of `$r` changes from "b" to "a". Since *both `$b` and `$r` refer to the same value*, the value of `$b` also becomes "a".

Finally if you do:

```
$r = "r";
var_dump($a, $b, $r); # a, r, r
```

Still only the value of `$b` to `$r` is changed, `$a` keeps its original value.

---

Back to your question, your first function is almost equivalent to:

```
function test_global_ref(&$r) {
    $b = "b";
    $r = &$b;
}

$a = "a";
test_global_ref($a);
```

I changed the variable names and values to those corresponding to the above example, hope this is easier to understand. So the global variable `$a` is passed to the function as a reference `$r`, when you copy the reference of `$b` to `$r`, the global variable `$a` won't be influenced.

Comment: So, changing the reference simply overrides the existing reference without affecting the initial reference?

Comment: Yes, each variable has its own reference, changing one's doesn't affect other's.